# Sharepoint IF statement for Aged days column

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list with the following columns [status], [date received], [aged days]. Currently [aged days] is a calculated field with the following:

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy"))-DATEVALUE(TEXT([Date Received],"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

which works and shows aged days since the date entered into [date received]. I would like this field to stop counting once [status] changes to "complete". How would I use an IF statement to achieve this? Thinking it would start like this but I'm stumped after that.

```
=IF([status])="complete",....
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following formula to achieve it.

**`=IF([status]="complete",DATEVALUE(TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy"))-DATEVALUE(TEXT([Date Received],"mm/dd/yyyy")),"")`**